# How to set datatype of SQL column in Alias?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a query such as:

```
select name as first_name 
from my_table
```

How can I set the datatype of that column in Postgresql to be character varying or anything in future - is there a way such as:

```
select name as first_name character varying
from my_table
```

I assume there is a way to set a datatype of a column after the aliasing - unsure how in postgresql

I am using postgresql and pgadmin4

Comment: `cast(name as character varying(100)) as first_name`. But I'd rather alter the table column instead to be varchar.

Comment: thanks - problem solved - can you please write it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: What is the current data type of that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cast` to change the data type:

```
select cast(name as character varying(100)) as first_name
from my_table
```

But I'd consider altering the table column instead, to be varchar(100):

```
alter table my_table alter column name type character varying(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use new datatype for column after **TYPE** keyword in PostgreSQL

> ```
> ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_datatype;
> ```

Let's take an example -

```
  CREATE TABLE Test (
        emp_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        emp_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    );

  INSERT INTO Test (emp_id, emp_name) VALUES ('abc00012','Shubham');

  ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN emp_name TYPE VARCHAR;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, I would use the short-hand syntax for type conversion `::`:

```
select name::varchar as first_name
```

Of course, the right thing to do is to fix the type in the table, but that is already covered by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

To easily cast your result to any datatype **use :: datatype** as in below:

```
select name as first_name ::varchar from my_table
```